# Android: Custom ArrayAdapter not working, getView() not getting called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am using `CustomArrayAdapter` with `ListView`. But, even after setting  `setAdapter` it is not working. Following are my code snippets:

**PastOrders.java**   Fragment displaying listView

```
public class PastOrders extends Fragment {
private View view;
private ListView pastOrdersList;
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Order> orders;
public PastOrders() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pastorders, container, false);
    context = getActivity();
    pastOrdersList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.pastOrdersList);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query  = ParseQuery.getQuery("Order");
    query.whereEqualTo("user_id", Vars.currentUser);

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if(e != null) {
                Log.e("TAG", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            } else {

                ArrayList<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();

                Log.i("TAG", objects.toString());

                for (ParseObject object: objects) {
                    Order temp = new Order();
                    temp.orderId = object.getObjectId();
                    temp.date = object.getCreatedAt();
                    temp.status = object.getString("status");
                    Log.i("TAG", "orderID: "+ object.getObjectId() + " temp orderID"+ temp.orderId);
                    orders.add(temp);
                    Vars.pastOrders.add(object);
                }

                Log.i("TAG", "after for loop past orders: "+ orders.toString());
                PastOrdersAdapter pastOrdersAdapter = new PastOrdersAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.past_orders_row, orders);
                pastOrdersList.setAdapter(pastOrdersAdapter);

            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
  }
```

**PastOrdersAdapter.java** Custom Adapter

```
public class PastOrdersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Order> {

private Context context;
private ViewHolder holder;
//private ArrayList<Order> orders;

public PastOrdersAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Order> orders) {
    super(context, resource);
   // this.orders = orders;
    Log.i("TAG", "POA adapter called");
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.i("TAG", "getView from POA");
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.past_orders_row, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.orderId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.orderId);
        holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        holder.status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);

        holder.details = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.details);


        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    ParseObject order = Vars.pastOrders.get(position);

    Log.i("TAG", "order id in adapter: "+ order.getObjectId());

    if(order != null) {
        holder.orderId.setText(order.getObjectId());
        holder.date.setText(getFormattedDate(order.getCreatedAt()));
        holder.status.setText(order.getString("status"));

        if(order.getString("status").equals("Delivered")) {
            holder.status.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        } else if(order.getString("status").equals("Cancelled")) {
            holder.status.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        } else {
            holder.status.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }
    }


    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {

    TextView orderId;
    TextView date;
    TextView status;

    ImageView details;
}
```

}

**Order.java**

```
public class Order {

public String orderId;
public Date date;
public String status;
}
```

**fragment_pastorders.xml** Layout File for Fragment showing ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/pastOrdersList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**past_orders_row.xml** Layout file for each row of listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orderId"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:textStyle="italic"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/status"/>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:id="@+id/details"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried printing getCount() as well and it is non-zero. I have tried everything. Kindly help

Thanks,

Arpit

Comment: Have you tried `extends BaseAdapter` instead of `extends ArrayAdapter<Order>`? @arpitgoyal2008

Comment: @Pooja: Thanks for your suggestions. I have tried `BaseAdapter` instead and it is working. But, I am still wondering why `ArrayAdapter` doesn't work. I have used `ArrayAdapter` before and worked always.

Comment: Post the relevant Log messages you got, skip the junk messages from log. In this case, it's hard to debug the code without knowing your log outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the constructor of your custom adapter, your forgot to pass your `orders` parameter to the parent constructor. So your adapter does not know what to display.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing empty list *orders* to you adapter. And then in adapter you are using different list: *Vars.pastOrders*.
So your adapter has empty list.
Replace this:

```
PastOrdersAdapter pastOrdersAdapter = 
     new PastOrdersAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.past_orders_row, orders);
```

with this:

```
PastOrdersAdapter pastOrdersAdapter = 
     new PastOrdersAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.past_orders_row, Vars.pastOrders);
```

Comment: Hi @questioner, I am actually population list orders as well. So, this is not the problem.

Comment: yes, you are right, I didn't see that, glad your problem is solved